# Do we really need NSCD service running? What are the pros and cons?

Tags: linux, dns, cache, sssd, winbind

We have a pretty mixed environment in terms of operating systems. Suse 12/15, Oracle Linux 6/7/8, Redhat 6/7/8 and a few others.

We've been using Active Directory authentication for some time.

For Linux clients, this authentication is done primarily using two type of integration:

- Most older systems use -->  Samba + Winbind + NSCD
- Newer systems use      -->  Samba + SSSD (no NSCD here)

We've had issue with dns caching and nscd was blamed for the problem.

My question is: Do we really need NSCD? What are the best practices for dns cache?

Our environment has around 4000 VMs (between windows and unix-like systems)

Comment: Every single system I have built in years, the first thing I always do is strip nscd out. May be useful in some enormous distributed workplace where many requests to a central database per second for ids etc are required, but for everyone else I think it is utterly pointless and should not be installed by default.

Comment: Thank you @Bib for your comment. Do you have any references that may be usefull to validate your response. I really need some documentation to convince guys here that we should remove nscd from our systems. 

I did find this site: https://jameshfisher.com/2018/02/05/dont-use-nscd/

But other than that nothing....

Comment: Nope, none at all other than sssd saying so. However, a quick interrogation of your setup will tell you if it is worth it. If you do not see many logins, spawning of processes by root to other users or other such id look ups, then it is probably not worth it, especially if you do not run a central registry of these things. After all, if id's & gid's are all local, then the o/s is probably going to cache passwd/group/shadow in memory anyway. Why not turn the question around, and ask people to prove that it is required? Ask then to provide the evidence that it reduces both cpu & network load.